# Empty results from r.fuzzy.set in GRASS 7.4.2

Tags: grass-gis, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to fuzzify a distance to roads tiff file using r.fuzzy.set in GRASS (installed with QGIS). I input the parameters (input layer, output, inflection points, fuzzy range, fuzzy boundaries etc and when I execute the tool it will finish in 0 seconds and the output will be empty. I have tried everything and I really don't know what could be causing the issue. The distances raster imports and shows perfectly in grass, but when I process, nothing comes out of it. the metadata shows only one cell:

> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+  | Map:      prueba@PERMANENT               Date: Mon Nov 05 21:58:04
>   2018    |  | Mapset:   PERMANENT                      Login of
>   Creator: K               |  | Location: prueba
>   |  | DataBase: C:\grass
>   |  | Title:    prueba
>   |  | Timestamp: none
>   | 
>   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|  |
>   |  |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0
>   |  |   Data Type:    FCELL
>   |  |   Rows:         1
>   |  |   Columns:      1
>   |  |   Total Cells:  1
>   |  |        Projection: UTM (zone 30)
>   |  |            N:          1    S:          0   Res:     1
>   |  |            E:          1    W:          0   Res:     1
>   |  |   Range of data:    min = 0  max = 0
>   |  |
>   |  |   Data Description:
>   |  |    generado por r.fuzzy.set
>   |  |
>   |  |   Comments:
>   |  |    r.fuzzy.set --overwrite input="distancias_autovias@PERMANENT"
>   output\   |  |    ="prueba" points="500,2000" side="left"
>   boundary="Linear" shape=0. h\   |  |    eight=1.
>   |  |
>   | 
>   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

While the input, the distance raster, shows correct metadata:

> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+  | Map:      distancias_autovias@PERMANENT  Date: Mon Nov 05 21:46:39
>   2018    |  | Mapset:   PERMANENT                      Login of
>   Creator: K               |  | Location: prueba
>   |  | DataBase: C:\grass
>   |  | Title:    distancias_autovias
>   |  | Timestamp: none
>   | 
>   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|  |
>   |  |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0
>   |  |   Data Type:    FCELL
>   |  |   Rows:         33402
>   |  |   Columns:      39587
>   |  |   Total Cells:  1322284974
>   |  |        Projection: UTM (zone 30)
>   |  |            N: 4834444.8198    S: 3999394.8198   Res:    25
>   |  |            E: 1013496.991    W:  23821.991   Res:    25
>   |  |   Range of data:    min = 0  max = 353793.7
>   |  |
>   |  |   Data Description:
>   |  |    generado por r.in.gdal
>   |  |
>   |  |   Comments:
>   |  |    r.in.gdal -a -k input="C:\grass\distancias_autovias.tif"
>   output="dis\   |  |    tancias_autovias" memory=300 offset=0
>   num_digits=0                      |  |
>   | 
>   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you didn't set the [computational region](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region) prior to compute the fuzzy set: the map "prueba@PERMANENT" consists of exactly one pixel as the metadata show.

You need to first run:

```
g.region raster=distancias_autovias -p
```

followed by further computations.